# Происходит утечка памяти в operator=

Tags: c++, память, перегрузка-операторов

```
BaseString& operator=(BaseString& s)
{
    len = s.len;
    p = new char[s.capacity];
    capacity = s.capacity;
    for (int i = 0; s.p[i] != '\0'; i++)
        p[i] = s.p[i];
    p[len] = '\0';
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 5):

Вы, конечно, не привели весь код, нет описания класса и т.д. — но ошибка типичная: вы попросту сделали/повторили конструктор копирования, перед этим не освободив уже выделенную для объекта память.

Проще (и глобальнее) всего — если у вас есть *корректно написанный* конструктор копирования, добавить к классу функцию обмена полей, что-то типа

```
void BaseString::swap(BaseString&s)
{
    std::swap(len,s.len);
    std::swap(p,s.p);
    std::swap(capacity,s.capacity);
}
```

Тогда присваивание легко записать как

```
BaseString& operator = (const BaseString& s)
{
    BaseString tmp(s);
    swap(tmp);
    return *this;
}
```

или даже

```
BaseString& operator = (BaseString s)
{
    swap(s);
    return *this;
}
```

И обратите внимание на `const` в первом варианте; не забывайте его писать, его отсутствие рано или поздно аукнется...

P.S. Конечно, можно просто добавить строчку освобождения памяти `delete[]p`, но тогда вы рядом дублируете код конструктора копирования, и нужна обязательная проверка, не присваиваете ли вы объект самому себе.

Comment: а буфер свопнуть `std::swap( p, s.p );`?

Comment: @DmitryK А, да, забыл! Конечно, все поля объекта.

Answer (score 2):

@Harry написал правильно. Если проще - оператор присваивания используется не только с новым объектом, в которм память под буфер не выделена. Если в Вашем объекте уже выделена через `new` память под буфер, то в вашей версии она как раз и утекает. Вы её не освободили, а просто указателю присвоили адрес нового выделенного куска памяти.

```
BaseString& operator=(BaseString& s)
{   // вот здесь - а если p указывал на уже выделенную память? То она утекает.
    p = new char[s.capacity]; 
}
```

Должно быть как-то так:

```
BaseString& operator=(BaseString& s)
{   
    if( p != nullptr )
       delete[] p;
    p = nullptr; // на случай если new в след. строке выкинет исключение
    p = new char[s.capacity]; 
}
```

И в конструкторе если сразу память не выделяется, то не забыть иницииализировать указатель `p = nullptr;`

Comment: Тут две ошибки - проверка `if( p != nullptr )` не имеет смысла, а после удаления указателю не присваивается нулевой указатель, что приведет к появлению в классе висящего указателя в случае, если `new char[s.capacity]; ` кинет исключение.

Comment: @user7860670 Абсолютно согласен, просто обработка исключений - отдельная тема. Вопрос был - где происходит утечка памяти в `operator=`.